# lightning:inputField is not rendering, saying the request is missing the field data when it is not

Tags: lightning-aura-components, controller, custom-field, lightning-design-system, custom-controller

I am trying to display a list of date ranges based on an objects start and end dates using a lightning component.  When I open it in a visualforce page as part of a set of nested components, it will not display the input fields.  When I inspect, the rendered HTML has a message:

> `"No input rendered: "
>   "Field "Flight_Start_Date__c" not found in response."`

The thing is, I can see the response providing the required field; in the apex controller, in the js controller, and in the lightning component if I use  and plug it in in place of the inputField.

EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION: I did this before with a different object and it worked just fine.  When I moved the start and end dates to this object and replaced the references, it stopped working.

Here is the component code:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.flights}" var="flight" indexVar="index"> 
  <lightning:recordViewForm recordId="{!flight.Id}" objectApiName="Product_Line_Item_Detail__c"> 
        <lightning:layout>
            <lightning:layoutItem size="12">
                <lightning:layout>
                    <lightning:layoutItem size="2" class="slds-p-top_large slds-p-left_small">
                        <lightning:formattedText value="{!'Flight ' +  (index + 1) + ':'}" style="align:center"/>
                    </lightning:layoutItem>
                    <lightning:layoutItem size="3" class="slds-p-right_small slds-p-left_small">
                        <lightning:inputField type="date" fieldName="Flight_Start_Date__c" value="{!flight.Flight_Start_Date__c}"/>
                    </lightning:layoutItem>
                    <lightning:layoutItem size="3" class="slds-p-right_small slds-p-left_small">
                        <lightning:inputField type="date" fieldName="Flight_End_Date__c" value="{!flight.Flight_End_Date__c}"/>
                    </lightning:layoutItem>
                    <lightning:layoutItem size="2" class="slds-p-top_large">
                        <lightning:button  onclick="{!c.deleteFlight}" label="Delete" value="{!index}" class="slds-button_dual-stateful slds-button_stretch"/>
                    </lightning:layoutItem>
                    <lightning:layoutItem size="2" class="slds-p-top_large">
                        <lightning:button onclick="{!c.updateFlight}" label="Update"  value="{!index}" class="slds-button_dual-stateful slds-button_stretch"/>
                    </lightning:layoutItem>
                </lightning:layout>
            </lightning:layoutItem>
        </lightning:layout>
    </lightning:recordViewForm> 
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
</aura:iteration>
```

Here is the js controller code to get the flights:

```
getFlights : function(cmp) {
        var component = cmp;
        var action = component.get("c.getProductFlights");
        action.setParams({productLineItemId : component.get("v.productLineItemId") });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if(state == 'SUCCESS') {
                console.log('Got flights');
                console.log('response = ' + JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue()));
                component.set("v.flights", response.getReturnValue());   
                component.set("v.newStartDate", "");
                component.set("v.newEndDate", "");

            }

        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
```

Here is the apex controller code:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Product_Line_Item_Detail__c[] getProductFlights(String productLineItemId){
    Id productId = productLineItemId;
    return [SELECT Id
            , Name
            , Flight_Start_Date__c
            , Flight_End_Date__c
            , Retail_Amount__c
            , Quantity__c
            from Product_Line_Item_Detail__c
            where Product_Line_Item__c =: productId 
            order by flight_start_date__c asc];
}
```

Edit:  I got it to work by replacing the fieldName with the field names of the object I was using before (Old Object Field Name = `Start_Date__c` vs. Current Object Field Name = `Flight_Start_Date__c`).  Why does this work?  I'm afraid it will stop working when I delete the other object.

```
<lightning:layoutItem size="3" class="slds-p-right_small slds-p-left_small">
    <lightning:inputField type="date" fieldName="Start_Date__c" value="{!flight.Flight_Start_Date__c}"/>
</lightning:layoutItem>
<lightning:layoutItem size="3" class="slds-p-right_small slds-p-left_small">
     <lightning:inputField type="date" fieldName="End_Date__c" value="{!flight.Flight_End_Date__c}"/>
</lightning:layoutItem>
```

Comment: Does `v.flights` property is set with a list properly?

Comment: Yes v.flights is defined like this:  `<aura:attribute name="flights" type="Product_Line_Item_Detail__c[]" access="global" />`

Comment: I actually just got it to work, but I don't understand why.  The previous object fields were called `Start_Date__c` and `End_Date__c`.  When I replace the inputField fieldName with `Start_Date__c` instead of `Flight_Start_Date__c` it seems to work again.  But I am planning to delete the object that I used before, and I don't know if it will stop working when I do that.

Comment: Put this answer in the official answer to your own question, so others don't think it's still an open question

Comment: @BrianMiller It's not an official answer though, it's some weird hacky thing that only works because I set it up that way before.   I'd like to know why it doesn't register the new field names.

Comment: Can you post the full line  of code that's working now for your `lightning:inputField`?  I think I'm missing something

Comment: Posted as an edit

Comment: I just ran into this error and this was the top result when searching for it. It's important to note that the `fieldName` on the `lightning:inputField` is **case sensitive**. If it doesn't match the API name exactly, you will see this error.

Comment: Important to note, for sure, but that wasn't the issue here.  The fields were working for the old names, and not the new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is related to caching.  I was able to change to the new object field names after a few days and some serious cache clearing efforts.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue trying to display an input field on a lightning-record-edit-form. The field did not appear and inspecting the DOM showed a message of

```
"No input rendered: "
"Field "MyCustomField__c" not found in response.".
```

It turns out the User did not have edit access to the field so it was fixed once I added that to the permissions.